# jQuery preventDefault stops rest of code working

Tags: jquery, default

I have this code where I am using jQuery to navigate to the next page, because I want some effects to take place before that happens. The problem is, that everything after the prevent.Default(); doesn't seem to work!

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".content-center").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
    navigate($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I need things to happen in that order, so that the animation happens and once it's complete - load the next page...

Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance?

Tim

---

Updated code (moves to new page but no animation occurs) ---

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var driver = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".content-center").animate({
        height: "0px"
    }, 500, function(){
        navigate(driver);
    });
});
```

see [here](http://www.nacremedia.com/swift/index.php)

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hey, thanks for both of your responses. My code now looks like this (updated above). The page changes but now the animation doesn't happen at all!

You can check out the page that I am working on here: http://bit.ly/aOeYgE

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the navigate method call in the the animation callback.

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $a = $(this);
    $(".content-center").animate({
        height: "0px"
    }, 500, function(){
        navigate($a.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

If you don't do this, the animation and the navigation will happen at the same time.

Rich

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to how stackoverflow works! Please see above!

Comment: You have an extra '});' between the click and hover event handlers.

Comment: Ah so I do! I've taken that out now though, and the animation works, but not the navigate! Argh!! Any ideas? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what navigate is, I'd use location.href = ($a.attr('href');

Answer (score 0):

Try using the callback function parameter of the animate function to implement navigation  once the animation is complete (from the hip):

```
$("a").click(function() { 
  var driver = this;
  $(".content-center").animate({height: "0px"}, 
                               500,
                               function() { navigate($(driver).attr('href')); }
                              ); 

});
```

Comment: Your example is the same as mine, but you've forgotten to prevent the default behaviour of the click, which will override the animation.